# How filter out Unique elements from a String and store them into an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream, unique

Given a filtered string. I want to add its substrings to an `ArrayList` only if it doesn't contain it already.

*My code:*

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile(",");
ArrayList<String> SANR = reg.splitAsStream(joiner.toString())    
        .filter(role -> role.contains("ABB"))
        .map(str -> str.replaceAll("ABB", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

As input, it gets all the values with `ABB` appended such as `[123,123,244,244,255]`, so I want to make sure the output is just:

```
[123,244,255]
```

Comment: Using set : Set<String> converted = Arrays.asList(str.split(",", -1)).stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());

Comment: do I add that after .map?

Comment: "use distict() if you want to use List" List<String> converted = Arrays.asList(str.split(",", -1)).stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: is this not possible:     ArrayList<String> SANR = reg.splitAsStream(joiner.toString())    
        .filter(role -> role.contains("ABB"))
        .map(str -> str.replaceAll("#ABB" , ""))
        .stream().distinct().collect(ArrayList::new);

Comment: You want only unique string without substring ``"#ABB"`, is it correct?

Comment: ya the outputs all work I dont want no repeated values, If theres any way there is fix using the code provided above

Comment: Possible, try to make code simple.

Comment: Is there way given string,  filter out all substrings that all have ABB in it just get the numerical values after it and basically add it into arraylist only if they are distinct

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) operation to ensure that the result doesn't contain duplicates. To achieve it and preserve the initial order of elements in the stream, it uses `LinkedHashSet` under the hood.

Don't use `ArrayList` as a type, it makes your code rigid. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

By the way, `Collectors.toList()` as well as Java 16 `toList()` operation will actually give you an `ArrayList`, but your code should not depend on it. If the in future there would be designed a better general purpose implementation of the `List` interface which will be capable of everything that `ArrayList` does, you'll get it for free if you would not demand specifically an `ArrayList`. Write your code against interfaces.

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile(",");
List<String> sanr = reg.splitAsStream(joiner.toString())
    .filter(role -> role.contains("ABB"))
    .map(str -> str.replaceAll("ABB" , ""))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Sidenote:* by [convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) uppercase-names should be used for constant fields (i.e. marked as `final`), for local values use camel-case starting with a lower-case letter. And names by itself should be meaningful, if `sanr` is a some kind abbreviation it should be documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If it fits your use case, I would suggest using a Set abstract data type instead of an ArrayList for this purpose. It allows you to not store any duplicates in the list of Strings.

Check out: [Java Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

If you'd like to keep it as an ArrayList you can do:

```
myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(myArrayList));
```

to delete any duplicates from "myArrayList"

Comment: Ya I know I could use Sets and HashSets but is there no other way with ArrayLists?

Comment: You can use the code I added to remove any duplicates from the list.